# Exporting AWS Data Pipeline as CloudFormation template to use it in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, terraform, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm trying to export **existing** [AWS Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/) task to [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) infrastructure somehow.

Accordingly, to this [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/4077), there is no direct support for Data Pipelines, but it still seems achievable using CloudFormation templates ([terraform resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudformation_stack.html)).

*The problem is that I cannot find a way to export existing pipeline into CloudFormation template.*

Exporting the pipeline with its specific [definition syntax](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-writing-pipeline-definition.html) won't work as I've not found a way to include this definition into CloudFormation. [CloudFormer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) does not support exporting pipelines either.

Does anybody know how to export a pipeline to CloudFormation or any other way to get AWS Data Pipeline automated with Terraform?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Feb 2019 update: a PR exists to solve this issue and is awaiting merge. You can use that fork if you don't want to wait: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/1538

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPD [Jul. 2019]: Some progress has been made in the terraform repository. [`aws_datapipeline_pipeline`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/datapipeline_pipeline.html) resource has been implemented, but it is not yet clear how to use it. [Merged pull request](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/1538)**

Original answer:

As a solution to this problem, I've come up with a node.js script, which covers my use case. In addition, I've created a Terraform module to be used in Terraform configuration.

[Here is the link to the gist with the code](https://gist.github.com/SorJEF/7f8c7b5f43e990d9a5a01c1f81fc9700)

Will copy usage examples here.

### Command Line:

```sh
node converter-cli.js ./template.json "Data Pipeline Cool Name" "Data Pipeline Cool Description" "true" >> cloudformation.json
```

### Terraform:

```hcl
module "some_cool_pipeline" {
  source = "./pipeline"
  name = "cool-pipeline"
  description = "The best pipeline!"
  activate = true
  template = "${file("./cool-pipeline-template.json")}"

  values = {
    myDatabase = "some_database",
    myUsername = "${var.db_user}",
    myPassword = "${var.db_password}",
    myTableName = "some_table",
  }
}
```

Comment: The new aws_datapipeline_pipeline resource seems to only track the pipeline with terraform. I'm missing the parameter pointing to the json pipeline config... Might go for your solution as well! Thanks